# Environment Variable is not going to container from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was trying to pass `ENV_VAR` to a container, but it was not working.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    ubuntu:
        image: ubuntu:latest
        environment:
            - ENV_VAR=teste
        command: "echo ${ENV_VAR}"
```

The problem was solved using `$$` instead of `$`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    ubuntu:
        image: ubuntu:latest
        environment:
            - ENV_VAR=teste
        command: '/bin/sh -c "echo $$ENV_VAR"'
```

But, I dont understand why I had to call `sh` and I dont belive that a running app inside my image will be able to read this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a variable in your container *at runtime* and having this variable available on *startup time* in your `docker-compose.yml` are different things. Compose cannot substitute variables somewhere in the config file with variables from the file's `environment` section – which you are trying to do in the `command` part, but you would have to use [an `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) to make this work.

Or, as you did, use the `$$` syntax to prevent Compose to [evaluate a variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution), but let it do the invoked Shell in the container.

The variables in the `environment` part are available to the container, though. You can check it with this minimal example:

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  foo:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: ubuntu
    environment:
      - foo=bar
    command: sleep 3
```

```
nico@tuxedo:~/StackOverflow$ docker-compose up -d && docker exec ubuntu /bin/sh -c "env | grep foo"
Starting ubuntu ... done
foo=bar
```

So your application inside the container should have no problem to get this variable.

As to why exactly `command: echo $$foo` doesn't work, I'm not entirely sure. I believe that if you use `echo` as `ENTRYPOINT` (because there is no other `ENTRYPOINT` defined [in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/010bf9649b1d10e2c34b159a9a9b338d0fdd4939/bionic/Dockerfile)), then there is no Shell when you start the container, because you overwrite the default `/bin/bash`. `echo` itself seems to be unable to read variables from the environment when there is no Shell "wrapped around it". Although the variables are clearly there (check this with `commmand: env` and `docker-compose up`), `echo` doesn't know how to get them.

If someone has a good explanation for this, I'm very happy to read it. :)